# SQL: full outer join (ambitious column name)

Tags: mysql

I have two table, t1 and t2.

```
-- t1
id  name      address
1   Tim        A
2   Marta      B

-- t2
id  name      address
1   Tim        A
3   Katarina   C
```

If I do t1 full outer join with t2

```
SELECT * FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

However, the result has ambitious `id`, `name`, `address`. 
How do I rename this so that I don't have duplicate column name?

---

**Attempt:**

```
SELECT name, address FROM

(SELECT * FROM t1
    LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM t1
    RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id) as derived_table;
```

---

return: ERROR- duplicate column name "name".

Comment: This question gave me a chuckle. I'm thinking the intended word was *ambiguous* (as in, open to more than one interpretation).  The column names `id`, `name` and `address` don't seem to be *ambitious* (having a strong desire and determination to succeed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ditch the `*` in the SELECT list.

Specify the list of expressions to be returned. And *qualify* all column references with either the table name, or preferably, a shorter table alias.

And assign an alias to the expression and that will be the name of the column in the resultset.

Also, the query shown is not equivalent to a FULL OUTER JOIN.

If the goal is return all rows from t1, and to also return rows from t2 where a matching row doesn't exist in t1, I'd do something like this...

```
  SELECT t.id            AS t_id
       , t.name          AS t_name
       , t.addr          AS t_addr
    FROM t1 t
   UNION ALL
  SELECT s.id
       , s.name
       , s.addr
    FROM t2 s
    LEFT
    JOIN t1 r
      ON r.id = s.id
   WHERE r.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try fully qualifying it like

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.address FROM t1
```